# Spring profile with annotation

Tags: spring, annotations, pom.xml

I have a profile created in my pom.xml

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
       <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <databaseUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orgdb</databaseUrl>
            <generateDatabase>true</generateDatabase>
            <maxIdle>10</maxIdle>
            <removeAbandoned>true</removeAbandoned>
            <username>root</username>
            <password></password>
        </properties>

    </profile>


</profiles>
```

I want to use the profile properties in my AppConfig class to set for example my dataSource parameters:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orgdb");
    dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
    dataSource.setPassword( "" );
    return dataSource;
}
```

Then be able to switch the active profile in my pom.xml. I can only find info about how to do this with xml files or with properties files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am listing out the steps what I have used for the same:-

1. Create a property file env.properties and register this in your AppConfig.java `@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:env.properties" })`
2. Now in your env.properties write the following `driverClassName=${driverClassName}` and so on..
3. Use **PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** in your AppConfig to read propertiy file as shown in code snippet

   `@Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }`
4. Use your property file variable as below

   `@Value(value = "${driverClassName}")
   private String driverClassName;`

Thanks.